# PHPMailer Failed to connect to server - Settings are correct

Tags: php, apache, email, phpmailer

I am testing SMTP on my server, using PHPMailer.
SMTP server works fine, on my VBulletin forums, but on my own website engine (from localhost, but port 80 is open, so I am doing it via my ip) I get the following errors:

```
2014-04-14 12:14:18 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  SMTP connect() failed.
```

I asked my mate, whom is the manager of the server, he says that there are no connections that are coming from my IP.

My PHPMailer settings:

```
public function create() {
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->isSMTP();
    $mailer->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";

    $mailer->host       = Config::$SMTP_HOST;
    $mailer->SMTPDebug  = 2;
    $mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mailer->Port       = Config::$SMTP_PORT;
    $mailer->Username   = Config::$SMTP_USER;
    $mailer->Password   = Config::$SMTP_PASS;

    return $mailer;
}

// SMTP details

public static $SMTP_PORT = 25;

public static $SMTP_HOST = "argonite.net";

public static $SMTP_USER = "recover@argonite.net";

public static $SMTP_PASS = "password";

public static $RECOVER_EMAIL = "recover@argonite.net";
```

And this is how I use it:

```
            $mailer = (new MailFactory())->create();
            $mailer->addAddress($email, $username);
            $mailer->setFrom(Config::$RECOVER_EMAIL, "Recover");
            $mailer->Subject = "Password Recovery - DO NOT REPLY";
            $mailer->AltBody = "Argonite has sent you your password as requested.";

            $mailer->msgHTML($this->buildMessage($username, $this->getPassword($username, $email)));

            if (!$mailer->send()) {
                $fh = fopen("logs/.mailer", 'a');
                fwrite($fh, "\n[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "]: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo . "\n");
                fclose($fh);
                return "An error has occured while sending your request. Administrators have been notified.";
            }
            else {
                return "success";
            }
```

Why is it failing? Could it be something with my PHPMailer settings, version or my Apache/php configurations?

php: 5.5.9

Comment: Change port to 567 for tls:
public static $SMTP_PORT = 567;

Comment: Is port 25 open on your firewall? is port 25 disabled by your SMTP provider? try port 26? 465 with SSL/ 587?

Comment: @RahulKaushik Doesn't work + yes I have port 25 open.

Comment: Also if I try to open port 567 - The entry already exists or its port is contained by another one.

Comment: `$mailer->SMTPDebug = 1;`

Comment: @Anthony Tried with 1, same errors.

Comment: @user3123545 You are using $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; and for tls, you need to use port 567 and it must be open... Or you can try below if you are using 25 port:
$mailer->SMTPSecure = "none";

Comment: New error after doing it on myserver, not localhost, with tls, and port 25: 2014-04-14 13:48:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO pk-x.com 2014-04-14 13:48:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2014-04-14 13:48:52 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 502 5.5.1 Error: command not implemented 2014-04-14 13:48:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SMTP connect() failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - I don't really know how but that's the settings I set:

```
    $mailer->SMTPSecure = "none";

    $mailer->host       = Config::$SMTP_HOST;
    $mailer->SMTPDebug  = 0;
    $mailer->SMTPAuth   = false;
    $mailer->Port       = Config::$SMTP_PORT;
    $mailer->Username   = Config::$SMTP_USER;
    $mailer->Password   = Config::$SMTP_PASS;
```

After adding secure = "none" and auth = false, and port 25, it worked.